# WPF - Button Image only visible in designer mode, invisible in run-time

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<WrapPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="42,0,174,0">
        <TextBox FontSize="20" Width="150" Height="26"/>
        <Button Width="30">
            <Image Source="Resources/Najdi.png"/>
        </Button>
    </WrapPanel>
```

Pretty much title. I tried various solutions I found on the internet, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Help please

Comment: There's nothing complicated here. Put the Najdi.png file in a folder named Resources in your Visual Studio project and set its Build Action to Resource.